# Accepted to PhD program but declined, but now want to return 3 years later

Tags: graduate-admissions

I got accepted to a PhD program at a university 3 years ago, sent an offer and everything but declined. Now I have secided I want to return. Is there any possibility of being admitted again without reapplying if I went and spoke with members of the department and graduate division?

Has anyone done this before? 3 years is a long time for sure but im curious if anyone was readdmitted without a defferal of admissions after 1 year.

Going back through old correspondance the faculty in the department were fond of me and hoped I would attend.

Any thoughts or insight appreciated thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can tell you anything you don't already know -- the normal process would not allow this, but there is a small chance that one of the professors you mention could arrange for an exception. Even estimating how often this happens is difficult, since your school may be totally different.

Comment: If you do reapply make sure you explain very convincingly why you have changed your mind and what you have been doing. Depending on the details this could be a huge red flag or a strong point of your application!

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar (2 years).  I just went ahead and reapplied.  5 of the 6 schools that accepted me previously did so over again.

Didn't even think about not doing the applications.  What's the big deal.  You should know how.  Let them run their process.

I recommend to apply to several schools.  Always good advice but in this case to hedge your bets in case "A" doesn't like how they were cold shouldered earlier.

I would try to put a positive spin on things but not dwell on the previous decline (no mea culpa).  'Have had 3 productive years doing X, but now see more than ever that my skills would better fit in a Ph.D. level position.'  Hopefully they still want you.  Of course for any schools that you didn't decline earlier, you don't need to mention it as much.  Just say you worked a while and decided you belong in Ph.D.

Answer (score 1):

Some programs will explicitly say that once given an offer, you can accept, defer for a year, or decline, with declining requiring reapplying if you want to be admitted again. Your offer may say something along those lines if you can fetch it.

If you'd like to check with the department and are uncomfortable reaching out to the professors, see if the department has a staff directory on its website. If there is an office coordinator or a graduate program specialist, they may be able to tell you if you have to formally apply again.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to reapply. However, reaching out to some of the faculty who were fond of you couldn't hurt, to let them know you are reapplying and tell them you are looking forward to meeting with them again.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Ive fallen out of touch with some of my old references is one of the reasons I was hoping I wouldnt have to reapply. I think that was the main thing holding me back, or hoping that I wouldn’t have to. Also I havent really been involved in the field these past couple years, not at all accually